# relocate ext4 structures to survive truncation

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I have a 6Gb raw disk image with 1 ext4 partition on it.
I have only 1Gb worth of data on it
Is there a way to reposition/adjust ext4 datastructures such that I can truncate the disk at 1 GB or 1.2Gb and still retain all the relevant structures

I want to do a dd of the 1.2Gb truncated image on a target volume and still create the original 6GB disk with all the partition info & ext4 journals/superblocks valid

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

To resize a ext2/3/4 volume, use `resize2fs`. You need to have the partition unmounted to shrink the filesystem. It will move your data (if needed), as well as any inodes, etc.

For example, if you wanted to shrink `/dev/sda1` to 1073741824 bytes (one GiB), you'd run:

```
# fsck -f /dev/sda1
# resize2fs /dev/sda1 1073741824
```

After that completes, you'd then change the size of the partition to be 1073741824 bytes (or slightly larger if you insist on aligning to a "track" boundary)

You may find the `-M` option (make it as small as possible) useful as well.

You can also expand filesystems with `resize2fs`; if you omit the size, it'll expand it to fill the partition.

If you're just wanting to back up some files to move to another disk, you should use backup utilities like `tar`, `afio`, `cpio`, etc. Or alternatively, disk imaging programs like `partclone` or `partimage` (which will only need to copy used space). Or dedicated disk imaging systems like Clonezilla (which will typically use one of those imaging programs under the hood).